# android AVD Issue

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Well, I know this has been already asked but i really need help, I've been trying to do this for hours!. My problem is that, when I'm trying to star an AVD i have an error

> PANIC: Could not open AVD config file: C:\Users\AndrÃ©s.android\avd\Motorola_DroidRAZR.avd/config.ini

I know the problem is because of the "accent" on my user name which is "Andrés", that's why it looks different (AndrÃ©s) which is not recognized by the IDE, so I need a solution, I'm desperate, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. List item Create a environment variable called: ANDROID_SDK_HOME and set it to C:\Users\Administrator
2. Open Eclipse > Window > Preferences and click in Run/Debug and String Substitution
3. Add a new variable called: user.home and set it to
   C:\Users\Administrator and Create an AVD and run it.

It should work now.

Comment: It doesn't work, now I have this error: PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\Administrator\.android/avd/Motorola_DroidRAZR.ini

Comment: 1, set the environment variable: ANDROID_SDK_HOME value of your SDK directory. As I have is: variable name ANDROID_SDK_HOME value of the E: \ java \ androidsdk
restart eclipse, reconstruction of the AVD can be run successfully
Modify the configuration file in the eclipse installation directory: Locate the following files: eclipse \ configuration.settings \ opened of org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs, in a later supplement to change just to configure the environment variables.

      As I add is: ANDROID_SDK_Home = E \: \ \ java \ \ androidsdk (Note that the slash format)

Comment: The SDK saves your AVD card in C:\Users\your_user_name_in_windows\.android\avd\
If your username in windows is not written with only english letters (for example, if your username uses non-english letters), it causes this problem.
The solution is to change your username in windows, or create a user whose name is written with only english letters.

Comment: I can change the username, but the user folder stays the same, so i cannot do anything

Comment: For all those frustrated windows users who will read my post in the future, THIS is how I solved it:
Setting a new envirroment variable, going windows>preferences>run/debug>String substitution in eclipse DID NOT HELP!
What helped is to link two paths using cmd.
mklink /J "C:\Users\John Doe\\.android" "D:\user\\.android"
If the retarded eclipse now tries to find the path "C:\Users\user\\.android" then windows will kindly direct the retarded peice of shit to the actual path "D:\user\\.android"

So to fix it do: mklink /J "wrong path" "correct path"

Comment: Sathish, thank's to you i discovered how to fix this. First i created a directory on D:\ called androidAVD then I created an environment variable called ANDROID_SDK_HOME with value D:\androidAVD then I opened the file on eclipse directory: eclipse\configuration\settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and I added ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\\androidAVD. Then I restarted eclipse and it worked. Thank you so much.